# Connect only once to Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**UPDATE:** While building an example, I found that the culprit seems to be `restify-enroute`. The package is messing with mongoose connection. I published the example to https://github.com/HeavyStorm/mongoose-enroute-conflict.

---

I had understood that mongoose.connect was how to establish a connection between mongoose and Mongo, and supposed that this was a singleton connection of sorts - once called, every module in my app would be able to call Mongo.

This is probably wrong.

---

My current scenario:

I'm calling connect:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");
```

My apps structure:

```
/
/app.js
/modules
   ./users
       ./module.js
```

In app.js I call `mongoose.connect`. I also load and expose a route from `module.js`. When I receive a http call, `module.js` code kicks in (I can see that from the debugger), but as soon as I call mongo (through `Model.find()` in this case), well, code skips, my callbacks are never called in the client is held on a waiting state.

**However**, if I add the `mongoose.connect` line to `module.js`, the Model.find() yields to the callback almost instantly and the client's receives the response.

**TLDR**: Do I have to call mongoose.connect on every module that access the database? Why is that?

Comment: Please show us your code. You should only need to connect once.

Comment: @LucasWatson I don't have code any more complex than what I told you. I can try and slap something together for demonstration purposes, but without running...

Comment: Is there a possibility that, since mongoose isn't rooted anywhere before the route code runs, it's collected by the GC?

Comment: @LucasWatson I added the example as you requested.